# Moving OracleVM Machines to ESXi

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, oraclevm

Is it possible to move OracleVM (v2) machines to an ESXi 4.1U1 machine? We have recieved these Oracle VM Machines, but we're only running on VMWare ESX machines.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [VMware Standalone Converter](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/converter5/dHclYnRqZEBiZEAldw==).  That may convert the raw VM files to work on VMware.  Alternatively, if the VMs you've received are running Windows, you can run the converter in the OS to convert the VMs to virtual ones.

Comment: The problem with the convert is (which i've tried) that it is giving me errors that it can't connect to the client i'm trying to convert.

Comment: Are you running the Converter within the VM Guest OS, or from a third party machine, or...?

Comment: Third party machine. The situation is even more complex... The machine 'm trying to convert and the ESX server cant see eachother. The VM i'm running the converter from has access to both subnets.